# How can I call a user with pyrogram?

Tags: python, pyrogram

How can I call somebody using pyrogram? I found `phone.RequestCall` and tried to do this but it doesn't work and throws the error:

> AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'phone'

I understand what it means, but how can I call it in another way?

```
app = Client("my_account", int(api_id), api_hash)
with app:
     app.phone.RequestCall(user_id=393664947)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyrogram itself does not support Calls via Telegram.

You'll have to use third-party libraries as "add-ons", like for example [pytgcalls](https://github.com/pytgcalls/pytgcalls).